# How to modify widget's innerHTML in Woocommerce

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, widget

I'm trying to show that one of the categories is on sale by displaying "ON SALE! -50%" text in category list widget.

[image: Without sale text]

[image: With sale text]

I obviously can't and won't modify category name to include this text.

Here's the website: https://demo.wpdesk.org/michalkleszko23gmailcom/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the fastest way how to do it is to write a short javascript, which will edit text. So, if yours widget has `id="block-5"` (according to the demo), you just add replacing script into the next custom HTML widget under the yours category widget.

```
<script>
document.getElementById('block-5').innerHTML = document.getElementById('block-5').innerHTML.replace("Albums", "Albums <div style=\"color:red\">ON SALE! -50%</div>");
</script>
```

Comment: I ended up going with slightly modified version of your script and it worked great. `<script> document.getElementById('block-5').innerHTML = document.getElementById('block-5').innerHTML.replace("Albums", "Albums</a><p style=\"color:red; display:inline;\"> ON SALE! -50%</p><a style=\"display:none;\""); </script>`.